# OAuth 2.0 and SAML - fine grained authorization

Tags: service, oauth, authorization, token, saml

In an OAuth 2.0 setting, suppose that, besides OAuth authorization (optionally using OAuth scopes), you want the resource server to use SAML assertions to implement fine-grained authorization checks, for example allowing certain operations only if the 'consumer' holds a 'Gold' status.

1) Is it possible for an OAuth acces token to "convey" a SAML 2 assertion? How?

2) If not, is there a way to use both Oauth and SAML 2 to obtain a similar result?

3) Is there a way to use OAuth by its own (without SAML) to obtain a similar result?

Please note that I know that you can use a SAML assertions as user credential when you are *getting a token* but here the point is different: what is needed is to use a SAML assertion when accessing to the resource, that is when *using a token*.

Comment: No answers? Could it be because the question is not clear? Should I add some detail to clarify?